# running a custom JS function from Flutter using webview package

Tags: flutter, webview-flutter

My Flutter app loads a webpage using the **webview_flutter** package.  I have successfully passed info from the webpage to Flutter, using **javascriptChannels**.  I have also successfully run built-in Javascript, from Flutter to the webpage. (Like launching an alert!)

But!  How can I execute a Javascript function ***on*** the webpagem from Flutter. (Not merely run a built-in Javascript methods?)

Say my webpage has a function called helloWord(), what is the dart code to trigger that function from Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

DOH!  I needed to add the "window" object to the front of the function...

So this code did the trick:

```
_webViewController.runJavascript('window.helloWorld()');
```

I am posting in case others have this issue.